# Alphanumeric increment in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, automation, jmeter, loadrunner

is there any why to increment Alphanumeric like

`A01,A02---A99,B01-----Z99.`

like this way, we used to work counter config element for increment numbers but this time we need along with alphabets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and some [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

```
for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= ('Z' as Character); letter++) {
    1.upto(99,{number ->
        def format = new java.text.DecimalFormat('00')
        log.info(letter as String + format.format(number));
    })
}
```

Demo:

[image]